# Is it possible to reduce the minimum width of a Preview window?

Tags: preview

I sometimes have numerous small images open (in separate windows) and I need all images displayed at the same time.  With each image centered in its window, there's a lot of wasted screen space.

If I can't reduce the minimum width of the window, is it at least possible to place the image along the left or right side of the window, allowing me to overlap the windows more effectively?

I've also tried viewing images in a web browser, but have the same problem.

Comment: Could you upload a screen image of what you're running against? You might be able to use a finder window/smart window to tile the images better, but it's hard to guess your workflow other than Preview isn't helping you out at the moment.